# How do I detect a touch or tap on a Ui image who is moving(animation)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm making a single view application where I want to detect a touch on a `UIImageView` that is going through an animation. All that the animation is, is that its showing the movement of the `UIImageView` from one side of the view controller to the other.This works when the animation is complet but not during the animation which is essential.

This is the code I have up to now:

```
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    image.hidden = false
    image.center = CGPointMake(160, 450) ;
    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(3, delay: 0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction  , animations: { () -> Void in
        self.image.center = CGPointMake(160, 70 )
        }) { (_) -> Void in    
    }
}
func handleSingleTapGesture(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    label.hidden = false
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    image.hidden = true
    label.hidden = true   
    let singleTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer =    UITapGestureRecognizer
    (target: self, action: "handleSingleTapGesture:")
    image.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
```

Thank you

Comment: add a UIControl to your UIImage, and then add a target to the UIControl

Comment: if your code that you have written is in view controller then in "viewdidload" is where u want to do that and if it is inside another view then "init" is where u want to do whatever @ogres suggested

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add it to your `UIImageView` , then animate view with `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction` option and when animation is completed , remove gesture recognizer ( so taps are not detected after animation )

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: "imageViewDidTap:")


Person1.hidden = false ;
Person1.center = CGPointMake(160, 450);
Person1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(3, delay: 0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.Person1.center = CGPointMake(160, 70 )
    }) { (_) -> Void in
        tapGesture.view?.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

and to handle tap gestures , create a method

```
func imageViewDidTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender)
    print(sender.view)
}
```

Comment: Where do I add the last part (func imageViewDidTap...)?

Comment: I didn't work. I found this way to detect a touch on a UI image who is not moving, but I need to be able to detect a touch when it is moving:

Comment: animate with UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, and it will work

Comment: It only works when i click the place where the Ui image ends (animation)

Comment: can you set Person1.userinteractionenabled = true ?

Comment: Yes but the problem is that the gesture is only recognized where the original Ui image is place. it doesn't follow the Ui image the during the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure whether it will work in your case or not, but

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   CGPoint point = [touches locationInView:self.view]  
   CGRect rect = self.Person1.frame;
   if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect,point)){
        // Touched within Person1 Image View
   }
   else{
        // Touched Outside Person1 Image View 
   }
}
```

Note: the above snippet is based on considering your ImageView is child view of self.view